# Как установить задний фон окна?

Tags: java, swing, background

осваиваю swing и возникла проблема, хотел установить картинку на задний фон, но ничего не происходит с чем может быть связано? И есть ли ещё какие-нибудь способы установки

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Image image = new ImageIcon("assets/background.png").getImage();
    g.drawImage(image, 3, 4, this);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На фрейме должна быть объект JPanel. И после можно установить фон-картинку. Первый способ переопределить метод JPanel

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("путь к картинке"));
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);       
}
```

Второй способ добавить лейбл

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("путь к картинке"));
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image ));
jpanel.add(label);
```